# wxPython TreeListCtrl showing mysterious boxes

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new to wxPython. I am having trouble getting the first column of a  wx.dataview.TreeListCtrl object to render properly. Specifically, the text in the first column for every entry has been replaced by black boxes.

[image: Black boxes on the first column in wxPython's TreeListCtrl]

Here is how I'm creating the control:

```
tree_list_ctrl = wx.dataview.TreeListCtrl(self.component_tree_panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.dataview.TL_DEFAULT_STYLE)

for c in ["Group", "Name", "Id"]:
    tree_list_ctrl.AppendColumn(c, 80)
```

And here is the data I'm adding:

```
root = tree_list_ctrl.GetRootItem()

for group_str in groups.keys():
    grp_node = tree_list_ctrl.AppendItem(root, "A GROUP")
    tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(grp_node, 0, "A GROUP")
    tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(grp_node, 1, "A")
    tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(grp_node, 2, "B")

    for child_str in groups[group_str]:
        child_node = tree_list_ctrl.AppendItem(grp_node, "A CHILD")
        tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(child_node, 0, "A CHILD")
        tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(child_node, 1, "a")
        tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(child_node, 2, "b")
```

I am using Python 3.7.4 and wxPython 4.1.0. This is a small part of a larger application with many controls - all others work as expected. It is only the first column of this TreeListCtrl that is causing me grief. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in that piece of code. The error must be somewhere else. Surely it is a problem establishing a bad parent of the widget when creating it.

Please, check and run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import wx
import wx.dataview


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    groups = {
            "G1" : ["a", "b"]
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):        
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.tree_list_ctrl = wx.dataview.TreeListCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.dataview.TL_DEFAULT_STYLE)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()


    ''' 
    Setting widgets properties
    '''
    def __set_properties(self):

        self.SetTitle("frame")

        # Creating columns:        
        self.tree_list_ctrl.AppendColumn("Group", 80)
        self.tree_list_ctrl.AppendColumn("Name", 80)
        self.tree_list_ctrl.AppendColumn("Id", 80)

        # Populating:
        root = self.tree_list_ctrl.GetRootItem()
        for group_str in MainFrame.groups.keys():
            grp_node = self.tree_list_ctrl.AppendItem(root, "A GROUP")
            self.tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(grp_node, 0, "A GROUP")
            self.tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(grp_node, 1, "A")
            self.tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(grp_node, 2, "B")

            for child_str in MainFrame.groups[group_str]:
                child_node = self.tree_list_ctrl.AppendItem(grp_node, "A CHILD")
                self.tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(child_node, 0, "A CHILD")
                self.tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(child_node, 1, "a")
                self.tree_list_ctrl.SetItemText(child_node, 2, "b")

    ''' 
    Setting layout properties
    '''        
    def __do_layout(self):        
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(self.tree_list_ctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MainFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

This is what you will get:

[image]

And as I say to everyone who starts:

**Use WxGlade builder to create GUIs with wxpython**. WXGlade generates clean code that helps to understand the use of WX, for example with sizers

http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/

Good luck!

Comment: Your snippet works fine. Since posting this question, I switched over to wx.gizmos.TreeListCtrl, which did not produce the glitch. I will investigate further. Thanks for your help.